# How to query all documents in mongodb that do not have a specific id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to return all documents that do not have the user's id in the document's followers array.

I am using mongoose with Node.Js but the regular mongodb way should be fine.

**EDIT**

Adding more info:

Here is an example document:

```
 {
  __v: 0,
  _id: ObjectId("53333273adf3ede81f0ce23b"),
  title: "fashion",
  date: 1395864179,
  followers: [
    ObjectId("53343ac3abcd1b6016c52c1b")
  ]
}
```

The query I tried to write but not sure if $nin is correct since the examples on mongodb are the opposite of making sure a field in the document does not equal an array of things, where I want to make sure an array of the document does not include a single element.

```
Story.find({followers: {$nin: [user]}}, "_id title", {$sort: {date: {{$gte: 30 } }, skip: 5, limit: 100}, function(err, results) {
```

The model:

```
var Story = new Schema({
    title: {type: String},  
    followers: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    date: {type: Number}
}, {collection: "stories"});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Story', Story);
```

The call to the server: (note I am converting it from a string to an object Id

```
GET /stories?userid=53343ac3abcd1b6016c52c1b&count=0 200 201ms - 2b
```

Comment: Lots of information here. But not sure what is relevant to your problem. You want to find all documents that do not have the "user's" id? What from? In followers? From every document? There surely is a much more simplified way of expressing what you want to do than what is in this question. Try to do that.

Comment: read the first line... it is as simple as it gets... i added info for people because I got some comments and someone who added an answer then deleted it was asking for more information

Comment: Hi, can you show any document structure having user's id in followers array ?

Comment: hey ammu, what do you mean exactly, you want to see the user schema?

Comment: may be $exists=>false can be used for checking if users id is present or not

Comment: wow nevermind this works I had the followers array as follower, messing up the query...

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with following query;

```
Story.inventory.find({followers: {$exists: true, $nin: [ "53343ac3abcd1b6016c52c1b" ]}},
                    {$sort: {date: {{$gte: 30 } }, skip: 5, limit: 100, function(err, results) {

});
```

This query will select all documents in the `User` collection where the `followers` field exists and its value does not equal to `53343ac3abcd1b6016c52c1b`.

Note: Do not convert id to Object, because mongoose does that for you.